# SyntaxError: Expecting Unicode escape sequence \uXXXX

Tags: node.js, next.js, babeljs, tailwind-css

This bug had been bugging us on our `nextjs` project(doesn't allow the project to completely compile). This seem to relate with `babel-plugin-preval` and `tailwindcss` configuration

```js
// Snippet of tailwind config extraction
import tailwindConfig from /* preval */ '../tailwind.config';

export const extractedTailwindConfig = tailwindConfig;
export const extractedTailwindTheme = extractedTailwindConfig.theme;
```

Photo of error:

[image]

I'm currently utilizing windows and it seem to flag out the macOS' /r. Removing all the new line and sticking everything together seem to fix it.